# smbclient automount via fstab asks for root pwd

Tags: samba, automount

I am working on Ubuntu gnome 16.04. I'm trying to mount a Samba share on a new computer. I have adapted the fstab and the credentials accordingly to the one on a second machine where everything works fine with my username and password

```
//XXX.XX.XX.XXX/share /mnt/gshare cifs    defaults,credentials=/etc/name.credentials,gid=1000 0 0
```

When mounting it (`mount -a` and when turning on the computer) I get prompted

```
Password for root@//XXX.XX.XX.XXX/name
```

Why am I asked for the root password and not the username and user password in my credentials a used? I am very new to this stuff but I assume somehow I'm trying to mount as root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the system is attempting to mount the drive as the root user, rather than the username defined in your credentials file. Make sure that your credentials file has the correct format:

```
username=your_name
password=your_password
```

Perhaps you're using `user` rather than `username` in the credentials file, which I believe will not work.

The line in your `/etc/fstab` file appears to be correct, when testing with the same configuration on my machine, everything worked fine.

I have noticed that `//XXX.XX.XX.XXX/share` is different in your fstab than `//XXX.XX.XX.XXX/name` in the error message, but am assuming that it's a typo in the question.

Comment: Thank you.  Embarrassingly I have to admit that the problem was in the credentials itself (additional character at the password). I have checked it several times and still didn't see it.

Comment: Finger trouble gets us all at some point! :)